# MASM Compiler Error: initializer magnitude too large for specified size

Tags: visual-studio-2015, imagemagick, jpeg, x86-64, masm

I'm trying to build a 64-bit Static C Library which dynamically links with the 64-bit C Runtime Libraries.

The C Library contains some assembly in one file which fails to build.  Here's the code below:

```
JMEMDOSA_TXT segment byte public 'CODE'
    assume cs:JMEMDOSA_TXT
    public _jdos_open
    public _jdos_close
    public _jdos_seek
    public _jdos_read
...
```

The compiler error I get is:

> A2071: initializer magnitude too large for specified size

Here's the link to the full asm source file:
https://github.com/cloudflare/jpegtran/blob/master/jmemdosa.asm

Comment: The linked source code is **not** a 64-bit-Windows source but a 16-bit-DOS source. I doubt you can build a 64-bit library with it.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I also discovered this as I was studying about 64-bit registers and decided to go with the C code for now.

You confirmed what I thought was the case.  I thought it was 32-bit, but even worse is it being 16-bit.  This certifies the C code is the way to go forward from here in the near term.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.  This assembly code is 16-bit, based on Michael's comment above.

To make this work with 64-bit requires it to be rewritten to use 64-bit registers.

It is impossible to have a 16-bit or 32-bit assembly compile as a 64-bit binary.

However, if there is C source code which does the same work, then the C code could be complied into the appripriate assembly and then compiled into either a 32-bit  or 64-bit binary.